# Using gsub to replace a period in R with blank but maintain other decimals

Tags: r

I'm using gsub to replace periods in the columns in this data frame with a blank. However, one challenge is in some columns there is numerical data that has periods in it that should not be removed, as they are used for decimal place value.

```
MeasurementCleaned <- gsub("[.]","",df$Measurement)
```

For example to remove the period I use gsub, but it also removes the periods in values in the column measurement as well. Thus 33.2 below will become 332 which I don't want the period to be removed here.

Desired Outcome:

Dataframe: df

```
DataID  Measurement    MeasurementCleaned
1       .              
2       33.2           33.2
3       32.5           32.5
4       .
```

Comment: Seems like `ifelse(df$measurement == '.', '', df$measurement)` will accomplish your stated goal, but you maybe you want to just do `as.numeric(df$Measurement)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Your Data
df = structure(list(DataID = 1:4, 
    Measurement = c(".", "33.2", "32.5", ".")), 
    .Names = c("DataID", "Measurement"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


df$MeasurementCleaned = gsub("(\\D|^)\\.(\\D|$)", "\\1\\2", df$Measurement)
df
     DataID Measurement MeasurementCleaned
1      1           .                   
2      2        33.2               33.2
3      3        32.5               32.5
4      4           .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sub("^[.]$","",df$Measurement)
[1] ""     "33.2" "32.5" ""    
 df$MeasurementCleaned=sub("^\\.$","",df$Measurement)
df
  DataID Measurement MeasurementCleaned
1      1           .                   
2      2        33.2               33.2
3      3        32.5               32.5
4      4           .
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine for doing exactly what you ask, but I used to work a lot with data formatted exactly like this. I found that if I was reading the data frame from a file, it was better to use the `na.strings` option to prevent the dots from appearing in the first place:

```
df <- read.csv('my_data.csv', na.strings='.', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```